# Jmeter for loop http request - parallel

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am using JMeter for image load testing.
I have an array of the image name and looping over that array, I am getting all the image via HTTP request.

```
-> loop_over_image - for loop controller
   -> http_request sampler
```

for now, it will loop and fetch images via HTTP sampler one by one.

It is possible to make these request parallel.

I am looping over 300 images - means 300 HTTP request, it is taking more than 5 minutes, but in chrome, it is taking 30 seconds because chrome API requests are ASYNC - means kind of parallel.

Is there any way to make these 300 request parallel. I don't think it is possible, because the loop will go to each image one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for the same solution.
I am extracting from an HTTP response a list of urls and assigning them into a variable (as array).
Parallel controller will not work in this case, since it does not accept an array as an input.

I think that there is not simple way to do it (possible using Java and JSR223Sampler).
JMeter dev community should add this feature to JMeter.

I've opened an enhancement request https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63526
Please vote up on it, so it will be implemented.

Comment: Sure, please do

Comment: @VinaySheoran Please share it with me also.

Answer (score 0):

Try with parallel controller or sampler.
Kindly check the below link:-

https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md

Hope this helps.